# Powershell script that will copy files to users in different groups - each group gets different files

Tags: powershell, active-directory

As a beginner I am having trouble with a rather straightforward task. I need to write a ps script that will copy files to users in different groups - each group gets different files. All files are on a network location, so I don't need to do anything on their computers.

First idea is to get a variable with all active users and then check to which groups they belong. If they belong to one of the three groups the script will copy the necessary files to their network location. There is a problem with one group for managers, as they belong to two groups that I am interested in, but I can probably fix that with conditions.

Most of the code I written for this are just snipets as the one below, trying to test PS out:

```
$Source = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))" #Import active users as a source variable
foreach ($user in $Source) #for every user in source get his groups
{
$UserGroups = get-aduser $user -Properties memberof | select -expand memberof
If ($user.IsMember("LDAP://" + ) -eq $False)
{
Write-Host "He is a member!"
}
```

I know it is not much, I have been searching the net for a suitable examples for over a week now with no luck.

Comment: If you're only dealing with 3 groups, why not pull a list of members from each of the groups and then iterate over them, copying the files to each of their network locations accordingly.  Seems like an easier solution than the way you're doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to test membership for a group:

```
$targetGroup1 = "Administrators"
$targetGroup2 = "Domain Users"

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties MemberOf | ForEach-Object {

    if(($_.MemberOf -match "CN=$targetGroup1") -and ($_.MemberOf -match "CN=$targetGroup2")) {
        "$($_.Name) is a member both groups"
        "copying files from a special location"
    } elseif($_.MemberOf -match "CN=$targetGroup1") {
        "$($_.Name) is a member of $targetGroup1"
        "copying files from source1"
    } elseif($_.MemberOf -match "CN=$targetGroup2") {
        "$($_.Name) is a member of $targetGroup2"
        "copying files from source2"
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @sodawillow, this is what I have been looking for, a way to test membership of a group. I have reworked it for three user groups I am interested in and will probably use this script. Too bad comments are too short to paste in the code. Have a good day!

Comment: You're very welcome. You can accept the answer by clicking on the green check under its votes, if you will.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe (code is untested):

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$groupOneMembers = Get-AdGroupMember Group1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
$groupTwoMembers = Get-AdGroupMember Group2 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
$groupThreeMembers = Get-AdGroupMember Group3 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

foreach($member in $groupOneMembers) {
    Copy-Item -Recurse \\server\GroupOneFiles \\server\Users\$member
}
foreach($member in $groupTwoMembers) {
    Copy-Item -Recurse \\server\GroupOneFiles \\server\Users\$member
}
foreach($member in $groupThreeMembers) {
    Copy-Item -Recurse \\server\GroupOneFiles \\server\Users\$member
}
```

Comment: Source and destination are always the same, and you should always test your code : ) this may create a `GroupOneFiles` folder inside the destination folder iirc.

Comment: Thank you @slashp, this code is waaay simpler I had it imagined to be. I tested it quickly and it does copy correctly. If I am in a hurry I can use your script to quickly copy files and just insert delete statements for group two and three, as there is some overlapping in our group memberships.